# Sprintf in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rounding, printf

Sort of a quick question. I'm writing:

```
puts "%.3f %.4f %.5f" % [3.998877, 3.998877, 3.998877]
```

and get the following output:

```
3.999 3.9989 3.99888
```

**sprintf** simply rounds the numbers. How do I restrict that rounding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>> 3.998877.to_s[/^\d+\.\d{3}/].to_f
=> 3.998
>> 3.998877.to_s[/^\d+\.\d{4}/].to_f
=> 3.9988
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>> def truncN f, digits
>>    t = 10.0 ** digits
>>    "%.#{digits}f" % ((f * t).truncate / t)
>> end
=> nil
>> n
=> 1.11181111
>> "%.3f" % n
=> "1.112"
>> truncN n, 3
=> "1.111"
```

Answer (score 1):

you will probably need to truncate the numbers to the accuracy that you want.

```
f = 3.1919183
puts (f * 1000).truncate() / 1000
```

Comment: sorry? could you give an example?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "restrict the rounding".  Specifically, what result are you looking for in your above example?

Comment: I just want my numbers 'as is': 3.998 3.9988 3.99887

Answer (score -2):

To get the numbers 'as is', you should store them as strings. As soon as you represent them as floats you lose information about the amount of built-in precision.

Comment: Why not store them as rational numbers instead?

Comment: depends what you want to do with them later, I guess.